# Code is unreachable Pylance but Code should be reackable?

Tags: python, function, printing, passwords

Issue: 
I am trying to make a zip cracker (not for illegal activities or what's not) but the area that prints the password couldn't be found has the issue `Code is unreachable Pylance`. How can I fix this issue?

Code:

```py
def main(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.signal_handler)
        if len(sys.argv[1:]) == 0:
            self._noargs()
        else:
            self._args()
        if self.passFound == False:
            print("Couldn't crack the password with the current options.")
```

Error:

```py
Code is unreachable Pylance
```

Code getting error:

```py
if self.passFound == False:
    print("Couldn't crack the password with the current options.")
```

Note: 
There are no quick fixes available in my IDE, which I use Visual Studio Code

Also if I put the code that gets the error in the beginning of the function it works, but I need it at the end.

Comment: You don't show any code that sets `self.passFound`.

Comment: If both lines are unreachable, then VS Code thinks both `_args()` and `_noargs()` do not return. The check for unreachable code is rather complex but it can also give false positives.

Comment: What do `self._noargs()` and `self._args()` do? If they both raise exceptions, you'll never get to the second `if`.

Comment: To reply to Barmar, it tells the program what to do if the user puts in arguments for the file to run or not, if not it will use inputs instead.

Comment: And both lines are unreachable @KlausD. How can I fix a false positive in this case if that is what it is?

Comment: I found out the reason for it, in my `_args` function at the end no matter what I had `sys.exit(1)` which is why it was unreachable.